# QGIS raster GeoTIFF file covert to kml?

Tags: kml, geotiff-tiff

I have a NDVI image, which I Geo-referenced in QGIS (raster).  Now I have to open the image in Google Earth - how do I convert the GeoTIFF raster file to a kml file in QGIS, so that I can open the image as a layer in Google Earth?

Answer (score 2):

These days you can use Google Earth Pro for free:

*Note: Google Earth Pro requires a license key. If you do not have a key, use your email address and the key GEPFREE to sign in.*

Google Earth Pro should be able to load directly your GeoTIFF (and save as something else if you need).

Comment: Try as I might I can't get Google earth pro to read in GeoTIFFs properly.

Comment: @HeinduPlessis I just dragged and dropped  GeoTIFF to Google Earth Pro now and it loaded no problem. If the size is over relatively small GEP maximum it will ask if Scale/Crop/etc. My testing GeoTIFF was created in QGIS in Float32 format. Maybe can't do Float64? Also custom projection might be an issue, not sure really.

Answer (score 1):

To display the image is Google Earth, your CRS has to be EPSG:4326. So re-project your image first if required.

Then, you can use gdal2tiles.py script which will create a KML SuperOverlay and you can view it in Google Earth.

http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html

Comment: I've done the following:gdalwarp -of GTiff -t_srs EPSG:4326 test.tif test2 tif  then gdal2tiles -p geodetic -k test2.tif which did create a doc.kml file.  If I open the doc.kml file in Google Earth, it takes me to the correct location - but no image is displayed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your input rgb or single band? Try to convert to 3 band and see if that helps.