# Create kml from binary raster

Tags: qgis, raster, kml, polygonize

I have a binary raster (values - 0 & 1) - I want to create a shapefile (KML for use in Google Earth) of the white area only (value = 1). Is there a simple method to do this?

[image]

Comment: I'm unsure what, if anything, you have tried already to accomplish this, but here is a similar question that uses GDAL to convert raster to KML. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143344/qgis-raster-geotiff-file-covert-to-kml

Comment: I think the best way is to extract the area you want into its own individual file first, then convert it to KML. You can do this by using raster calculator to extract the area marked as "1" (Raster Calculator Tool); then convert to .kml (via .shp or polygon is you want)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with [`gdal_polygonize`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) in one go:

`gdal_polygonize -mask binary-raster.tif binary-raster.tif -f KML output.kml`

The `-mask` option is used to only regard non-zero values as valid - therefore keeping only the white area of your image.

In QGIS you can find `gdal_polygonize` under Raster -> Conversions -> Polygonize.