# Convert GeoTiff to KML

Tags: kml, kmz

I am new to QGIS and would like to convert some GeoTiff images to KML/KMZ for distribution to non-GIS users to look at in Google Earth. I have recently left the Windows OS and I am running QGIS in Linux-Ubuntu. I have not yet successfully installed GE Pro on this OS. In the past I would have used Arc, Global Mapper, or GE Pro to do this.

Can someone point me to a work around?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate KML SuperOverlay KML that points to folder of tiles or KMZ file
with GDAL2TILES.py that comes with GDAL.  Even better, you can use GDAL2TILES_Parallel.py 
Commercial Software can also do this such as Global Mapper, Map Tiler and others

If you have WMS or TMS/XYZ Tile Server you can also generate KML via MapProxy

Google Earth Pro (which is free) can work with Tiff.  It can also load WMS

[QGIS raster GeoTIFF file covert to kml?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143344/qgis-raster-geotiff-file-covert-to-kml)